# Crear una lista de listas

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Necesito crear una lista (lista principal) que contenga dentro otras listas secundarias. Las listas secundarias se cargarán con valores fijos.
Estoy utilizando `Java` en `Android Studio Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2`.

```
public class ClasificacionListaPPA {
    public int cfm;
    public double diametro;
    public double perdida;

    public ClasificacionListaPPA(double dia, int flujo, double perd) {
        diametro = dia;
        cfm = flujo;
        perdida = perd;
    }
}

public class LoadListas {
    List<List<ClasificacionListaPPA>> listaPPA;
    List<ClasificacionListaPPA> listaDiametros;

    public void LoadListaPPA() {
        listaDiametros = new ArrayList<ClasificacionListaPPA>();
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(1.5,30,10.00));
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(1.5,29,9.00));
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(1.5,27,8.00));
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(1.5,26,7.00));
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(1.5,24,6.00));
        //...
        //...
        //...
        listaPPA.add(listaDiametros); //Posible problema.

        listaDiametros = new ArrayList<ClasificacionListaPPA>();
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(2,66,10.00));
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(2,63,9.00));
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(2,59,8.00));
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(2,55,7.00));
        listaDiametros.add(new ClasificacionListaPPA(2,51,6.00));
        //...
        //...
        //...
        listaPPA.add(listaDiametros); //Posible problema.

        //...
        //...
        //...      
    }
}
```

Hice una depuración por lineal y cuando se ejecuta la instrucción " listaPPA.add(listaDiametros); " el `AndroidStudio` me dirige a la clase " ActivityThread.java " ejecutando el catch:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    if (!mInstrumentation.onException(activity, e)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(
            "Unable to start activity " + component
            + ": " + e.toString(), e);
    }
}
```

Luego de esto se cierra la app en curso.
¿Estoy agregando la lista secundaria dentro de la lista primaria de manera incorrecta?

Comment: El error es porque no has inicializado `listaPPA`

Comment: Gracias, me pasa por programar con sueño.

Answer (score 1):

Me falta inicializar la listaPPA

```
listaPPA = new ArrayList<>();
```